# command to track user rollback and see which user is committing maximum manual rollback

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know the oracle command to track down those who do manual rollback and the type of process for which they are doing rollback.

Comment: You have tagged this question with two database engines (MySQL and Oracle). Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: Also clarify what you mean by "rollback". Are you talking about individual transactions, or an entire database flashback-type of operation?